# Enthalpy Change in Reversible, Isothermal Expansion of Ideal Gas

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, carnot-cycle

For the reversible isothermal expansion of an ideal gas:
$${∆H}={∆U}=0 \tag1$$
This is obvious for the case of internal energy because 
$${∆U} = \frac {3}{2} n R {∆T} = 0 \tag2$$
and
$${∆U} = -C_P n {∆T} = 0 \tag3$$
For the case of enthalpy it is easy to see that
$${∆H} = -C_v n {∆T} = 0 \tag4$$
I've also seen
$${∆H} = ∆U + ∆(PV) = ∆U + nR{∆T} = 0 \tag5$$
Now for the part I don't understand.
$$dH = dU + PdV \tag6$$
$$dH = dU + nRT \frac {dV}{V} \tag7$$
$${∆H} = {∆U} + nRT \ln\frac {V_2}{V_1} \tag8$$
$${∆H} = 0 + nRT \ln\frac {V_2}{V_1} = \ln\frac {V_2}{V_1} ≠ 0\tag9$$
Clearly, it is incorrect to make the substitution $ P = nRT/V$ in going from $(6)$ to $(7)$. Why is that? I thought equation $(6)$ was always valid, and integrating such a substitution should account for any change in the variables throughout the process. Why does this not yield the same answer as $(4)$ and $(5)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$H = U + PV \Rightarrow$$

$$dH = dU +PdV + VdP\tag{6}$$

In other words, equation 6 is missing the $VdP$ term.

$$dH = dU + nRT \frac{dV}{V} + nRT \frac{dP}{P}\tag{7}$$

$$ \Delta H = \Delta U + nRT \ln\frac{V_2}{V_1} + nRT \ln\frac{P_2}{P_1}\tag{8}$$

$$P_1 V_1 = P_2 V_2 \text{ (isothermal)}$$

$$\Delta H = \Delta U + nRT \left( \ln\frac{V_2}{V_1} + \ln\frac{V_1}{V_2} \right) = \Delta U = 0\tag{9}$$

Comment: I've never seen it written with a $ VdP $ term. My book presents it as written in $ (6) $ for an ideal gas. Are there certain situations in which $ VdP $ must be included, and others where it is acceptable to just use $ PdV $?

Comment: Books omit the VdP term for constant pressure situations, because it is zero. All other situations require the VdP term. H = U + PV is by definition.  Then, using the product rule for derivatives you immediately obtain dH = dU +PdV + VdP.

Comment: In the Carnot cycle, the amount of work done in moving along an isotherm is calculated without the $ VdP $ term. In looking at the PV diagram, the pressure isn't constant. How can the term be ignored in such a case then?

Comment: Is it because P varies as a function of V? Whereas in the situation I described it does not? The situations seem analogous to me, but they are clearly not.

Comment: H is enthalpy, not work. dW = Fdx = PAdx = PdV, where F is force, x is distantce, A is area.

Comment: Ok, I realize I have described two separate situations. Thanks for your help. My confusion centered around actually taking the derivative of $ H $. I was blindly following the book (no $ VdP $ term) without thinking about what was actually being done (differentiation).

Answer (score -2):

$$PV =nRT$$
So, for constant temperature, $dU=0$.

$H=U+PV$

The term $d(PV) = 0$   because $PV$=constant

So, $dH=0$